# React showing errors when i use methods of map and other

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello im using react and axios and i need some data from api.
So the question is why i getting errors all the time when i try to use methods in my jsx.

For example the map on the bottom of a code and the same thing with a slice medthod.

Also it works only if i didnt refresh the page.

Here is Benifits using map method on the last line but without refresh [image]

```jsx
import React from "react";
import axios from 'axios';
import ribbon from './../../img/ribbon.png'
import share from './../../img/share.png'
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

function withParams(Component) {
  return props => <Component {...props} params={useParams()} />;
}


class JobPage extends React.Component {
  
  componentDidMount() {
    {
      let id = Object.values(this.props.params);
      console.log(id[0])
      axios.get('https://api.json-generator.com/templates/ZM1r0eic3XEy/data?access_token=wm3gg940gy0xek1ld98uaizhz83c6rh2sir9f9fu')
        .then(response => {
          this.props.setCurrentJob(response.data[id[0] - 1])
        });
    }
  }
  

  render() {
    {console.log(this.props);}
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="flex border-b-2">
          <div>Job Details</div>
          <div className="flex items-center"><img className="w-3 h-3 " src={ribbon} alt="img" />Save to my list</div>
          <div className="flex items-center"><img className="w-3 h-3 " src={share} alt="img" />Share</div>
        </div>
        <div>Apply Now</div>
        <div>{/* Общий*/}
          <div>
            <div>{this.props.currentJob.title}</div>
            <div>
              <div>{this.props.currentJob.salary}</div>
              <div>Brutto, per year</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>Posted:{this.props.currentJob.createdAt}</div>
          <div>{this.props.currentJob.description}</div>
          <div>Responsopilities</div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quas, vero neque laborum similique facilis aliquid
            recusandae! In mollitia dolorum earum eius alias voluptates. N
            am id fugit vel optio reiciendis mollitia facere minima deserunt, dolores nemo? Dolore, quo magni, cum iste in eius deserunt nam rerum quos ipsum fuga error?</div>
        </div>
        <div>Compensation & Benefits:</div>
        <div>{this.props.currentJob.benefits.map(b=><div>{b}</div>)}</div>
      </div>
      
    )
  }

}
export default withParams(JobPage);
```

and here is the refreshed page and the error

[image]

Comment: you query the data when the component is mounted -> you wait for the data to arrive. but while you wait, React tries to render the data; data that is not yet in the state, as it hasn't arrived. you could check for the length of `currentJob`s, and only `.map` if it's at least 1. (this is the first guess based on the info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React will not wait for your request to succeed to render the page.

Axios get method is asynchrone. Once Axios receive a response from the API you set the value of currentJob by calling setCurrentJob.

During this time, React will try to execute currentJob.benefits.map. Even though, currentJob is undefined as the request may not have finished yet or failed.

So Make sure to null check the value of your state before accessing the properties of your state.